# Proving non-existing limit using the path method

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have the following question:

> $$
> f(x,y,z) = 
> \begin{cases}
> {\frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{|x| + y^4 + z^2};\space\space  (x,y,z) \ne (0,0,0)}  \\
> 0\space\space \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space;\space\space\space\space (x,y,z) = (0,0,0)
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> Does $(0,0,0)$ is a continous point in $f$?

My answer:

> No , because in order that this point will be continous $\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)} f(x,y,z) = f(0,0,0)$
>
> $$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)} f(x,y,z) = \lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)} \frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{|x| + y^4 + z^2}.$$
>
> Take $\{x = z = y^2\} = \frac{m^2y^4 + y^2 + m^2y^4}{|my^2| + y^4 + m^2y^4} = \frac{m^2y^2 + 1 + m^2y^2}{|m| + y^2 + m^2y^2} = \frac{m^2 + \frac{1}{y^2} + m^2}{\frac{|m|}{y^2} + 1 + m^2} = \frac{2m^2 + \frac{1}{y^2}}{\frac{|m|}{y^2} + 1 + m^2} = 2my^2 + 2m^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{|m|} + \frac{1}{y^2} + \frac{1}{m^2y^2}$ so limit no exist, then no continuity.

## My question to you:

The limit I found is $2my^2 + 2m^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{|m|} + \frac{1}{y^2} + \frac{1}{m^2y^2}.$

Is that valid to say that the limit not exist because of path-dependent? (contain $m$)

or should I cancel out $x,y,z$, and just them I can talk about path dependency?

Thanks in advance!

Note: this is a example. Im talking in general about prove non-existance of limit because of path-dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(0,y,0) = \begin{cases} {1 \over y^2}, & y \neq 0 \\
0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand what are you trying to say

Comment: Well, note that $\lim_{y \to 0} f(0,y,0) = \infty$, but $f(0,0,0) = 0$, so $f$ cannot be continuous at $(0,0,0)$. (If $f$ was continuous, you would have $\lim_{y \to 0} f(0,y,0) = f(0,0,0)$.)

Comment: Nice point, didn't think about it. but it's just an example, the main point is if I can prove non-existance even if I have x,y or z in the limit

Comment: You can. You need to show that for some $\epsilon>0$, that you can find at least one point arbitrarily close to $(0,0,0)$ such that $|f(x,y,z) -f(0,0,0)| > \epsilon$. Finding a path will work, but any method that does this is sufficient.